# What's the difference between CMs "push" method (Ansible) to "pull" method (Chef/Puppet)?

Tags: configuration, ansible, architecture, puppet, deployment

I know that some of the advantages of Ansible over many other CMs are these:

1. Ansible's scripts being written in YAML, a simple serialization language.
2. The fact that one doesn't have to install it on the machines you deploy its commands/playbooks.
3. Ansible's strong user base and community (for example, galaxy-roles)

I know there is another bold different, using the "push" method" instead of some other CMs using the "pull" method.

What is the difference here? Maybe it reflects difference 2?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking for a comparison between the agentless architecture of Ansible against the master/agent architecture of Puppet? Or are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: Note that ansible _can_ be used in pull mode; see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ansible-pull.html

Comment: @Haxiel I assume I do ask on the difference you mention (if that's likeliest for "push"/"pull").

Comment: Looks like: https://serverfault.com/questions/568187/configuration-management-push-versus-pull-based-topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ansible push mode, a centralized server connects to other target servers and runs a series of commands to set the target servers into a desired state. Because the centralized server can potentially serve hundreds or thousands of target systems, this can put quite a bit of load on the centralized system.

In pull mode, each system acts as its own server, allowing for greater scalability since no single server is forced to take on a high load of serving many target systems.

[Ansible Pull Documentaion](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ansible-pull.html)

Comment: +1. Wouldn't you say than then pull is always better than push? Like learning someone to grow their own vegetables instead giving them just vegetables?

Comment: A pull model distributes the load, at the added cost of a small bit of configuration, resulting in scalable deployments. "Always" isn't an engineering term, there are too many tradeoffs to make.